# R function that re-plugs in its output

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a HW problem where I have simulated data and have to do gradient boosting.  I think I understand the substance of gradient boosting but I'm having problems setting up a loop.

"f" is a list of 400 trees that are calculated with the tree() function, which involves "r" which is initially defined outside of the function.

"r" is recalculated based on the first "f" and then plugged back into the tree() function

So basically, we need 400 "r" but r[1] is already defined. We also need 400 "f" with f[1] being a function of r[1], and with f[2] using the "r" calculated from f[1], with the process being repeated until we have 400 "f"

I hope this explanation makes sense (it seems simple in my head).  This seems like it's probably a simple loop but I have such a hard time with programming in general that I'm having problems writing even the pseudo code.

```
#Simulate data set
N=1000
X1=runif(N)
X2=2*runif(N)
SNR=10
Y=sin(10*X1) + 2*(X2^0.5)
sigma=sqrt(var(Y)/SNR)
Y=Y +rnorm(N,0,sigma)
newdat<-data.frame(c(Y,X1,X2))

#3a:  List of all boost trees
f=list()
r=Y

#3b:  Fit regression tree and calculate residual 
#THIS CODE IS NOT CORRECT AND IT'S WHAT I NEED HELP WITH
for(i in 1:400){
  f[[i]]=tree(r~X1+X2, data = newdat, control=tree.control(nobs = 1000,mincut = N/4)) 
r[2]=residuals(f[[1]], type="usual")
}
```

Comment: At a first glance try using `i+1` and `i` instead of `2` and `1`. Not sure about whether you are returning `r` as a list or a vector

Comment: I believe that each "r" is a vector of length = 1,000

Comment: make sure you understand the difference between list and vector, if `residuals` will return a vector you cannot insert it into an index of `r`. `r` needs to be a list to do that

Comment: Ok.  I think I figured it out.  I defined "r" as a list outside of the function and set r[1] outside as well.  Then I used [i] and [i+1] in the function.